# How to clean uninstall Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?

Tags: pdf, crash, macos

Having to fill a government document I was suggested to install the
last version of Adobe Acrobat Reader DC on my Mac (10.10.4).

I downloaded version 2015.009.20069 from Adobe server.

This software crashed 3 times on very basic PDF documents.
I didn't find anyway to print a document.
My root umask is `022` and nonetheless, this software installed in
`/Applications` with a mode of `775` which is a plain violation of my security settings.

Hence I would like to uninstall it. Unfortunatly, there is no uninstaller included with the package installer.

I thought this is because this software was a basic install of just
`/Applications/Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.app`.
Just to be sure, I made a fast find of all files arrived on my Mac
at the same time and discovered **2083** of them within:

```
/Library/Application Support
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/Library/Preferences
/Library/PriviledgedHelperTools
${HOME}/Library/Application Support
${HOME}/Library/Preferences
```

This isn't exactly what one can name a clean and simple install.

---

Is there any **complete** and **simple** uninstaller of this piece of [censored] software?

Comment: Have a look at: [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I didn't find any professionnal answer on the Adobe server.
Hence I had to make it.

Here is the shell script I wrote with the help of another tool:
[Find all files modified around a known one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252317/find-all-files-modified-around-a-known-one/253217#253217) and which I fully tested after an unwanted install (on Yosemite 10.10.4).

Of course, this shell has to be run as `root`. This is why I
added the `set -ex` to check exactly which command is executed and to exit in the case of any error.

```
#!/bin/sh

# shell script to clean all files created or modified 
# during the install of Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

# exit on error and echo commands

set -ex

# check if a directory is empty
is_empty() { [ -z `find $1/. ! -name . -print -prune | head -1` ] ; }

# rm left empty dir
rm_ifempty() {
        if is_empty $1 ; then
                rm -rf $1
        else
                echo $1 not empty
        fi ;
}

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# stop and remove daemons

cd /Library/LaunchDaemons

launchctl unload com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator.plist
rm -f com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator.plist

launchctl unload com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper.plist
rm -f com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper.plist

cd /Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl unload com.adobe.ARMDCHelper.*.plist
rm -f com.adobe.ARMDCHelper.*.plist

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# remove the application

cd /Applications
rm -rf Adobe\ Acrobat\ Reader\ DC.app


# remove system wide preferences

cd /Library/Preferences
rm -f com.adobe.reader.DC.WebResource.plist

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# remove all Application dependant ressources

cd /Library/Application\ Support/Adobe
rm -rf ARMDC
rm -rf ARMNext
rm -rf HelpCfg
rm -rf Reader/DC

# Reader/11.0 should be kept
# if Reader directory is empty remove it

rm_ifempty Reader

cd /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/
rm -rf AdobePDFViewer.plugin
rm -rf AdobePDFViewerNPAPI.plugin

cd /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools
rm -f com.adobe.ARMDC.*

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# remove HOME dependant ressources

cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Adobe
rm -rf AcroCef
rm -rf Acrobat/DC


# Acrobat/other_versions shoud be kept
# if Acrobat directory is empty remove it

rm_ifempty Acrobat

rm -rf Linguistics

cd ~/Library/Application\ Support
rm -rf CEF

# crash dumps
cd ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
rm -rf AdobeReader_*.crash

cd ~/Library/Preferences
rm com.adobe.AdobeRdrCEF.plist

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# remove receipts files

cd /private/var/db/receipts
rm com.adobe.RdrServicesUpdater.*
rm com.adobe.acrobat.DC.*
rm com.adobe.armdc.*
```

Comment: Now I fully understand why Adobe never wrote a clean uninstaller for their different versions of Adobe Readers !

Comment: worked fine for me, except that I didn't have a `com.adobe.AdobeRdrCEF.plist`. Instead I had:
```com.adobe.AdobeRdrCEFHelper.plist
com.adobe.Reader.plist
com.adobe.crashreporter.plist
```
Maybe the should be updated to use the `-f` option. Many thanks anyway.

Comment: There seems to be some Acrobat-related files still lying around. After running this and trying to install the latest Acrobat available from their site, I get the error "Found a higher version Adobe Acrobat Reader in the installation location. Installation will terminate." during the install. Also tried the CC Cleaner tool from Adobe's site, same error.

Comment: @amergin: Which version of MacOS X are you running? Did you locate one of the remaining files? Is the application still on your Mac?

Comment: @amergin I was getting the same error ("Found a higher version..."). Incredibly the problem turned out to be the installer finding Adobe files in the trash! Try emptying it.

Comment: @WoodenKitty LOL dude you totally saved me was exactly my previous version in the trash! TY

Comment: @amergin : you shouldn't find anything in your Trash, since my script is exactly made to avoid this above all. It is stopping all the daemon and then only using `rm` so as to avoid ghosts in the Trash .

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to Uninstall applications.  Macworld.com had written about a product from FreeSoftMac called [App Cleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) that does exactly this type of uninstall.

You can also have a look at this similar question:  [How to Uninstall Qt in El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231743/how-to-uninstall-qt-in-el-capitan/231785#231785)

I don't have Adobe installed on my Mac at this time, but I do have software that installed Launch Daemons - [Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/) - which I am going to uninstall because I am finished with my drive recovery.  Below is a screen capture of what it finds and will remove from the system; the arrow points to the Launch Daemon associated with Disk Drill.

[image: DiskDrill Screen Shot]

Comment: I tested it on a case of a software which installed like a herd of pigs: `Foxit` (Many installed directories with mode `777` ). I tested `App Cleaner`.•• return ••This little app is a pretty nice piece of work!

Comment: App Cleaner is a great program, but it's not up to cleaning the mess Adobe makes. Specifically, it doesn't remove the files from `/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, and `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools`. I know because I just tried it and those files were all still there.

Comment: @SSteve: [ad] my script does it :).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work; about to try it now.  I have used CleanMyMac through multiple versions; just installed CMM3 on my new Sierra-running MacbookPro; it does complete uninstalls of programs/applications, so I imagine it will work for Reader.  Now all I ahve to do is find Reader 11!  (or move it from back-up disk, I guess)