# How to Uninstall Qt in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, open-source

I know the thread [How to uninstall Qt Creator on Mac Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26750250/54964) but I cannot locate Qt folders in $HOME/Library/.
The following command is also unsuccessful

```
sudo QtSDK/SDKMaintenanceTool.app/Contents/MacOS/SDKMaintenanceTool
```

I think Qt version is 5.1. The whole package took about 14 Gb which I cannot keep anymore in my system.

---

How can you uninstall Qt in El Capitan?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New location of Qt folders is at `/Users/Masi/Qt` where you can find `SDKMaintenanceTool` which you just double click and select uninstall all components. Source [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Howto_do_a_clean_uninstall_and_reinstall_of_qt_sdk).

Comment: This was the right solution. However, the app's name was `MaintenanceTool.app`. I had El Capitan and Qt 5.5.

Answer (score 2):

When I have to uninstall apps on a Mac, there is a utility that was reccomended by [Macworld.com](http://www.macworld.com/article/2995495/operating-systems/remove-extra-application-files-with-appcleaner.html) that has been an indespensible tool in my Mac toolbox:  [FreeMacSoft's AppCleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)

It has a super easy to use Drag-n-Drop interface or (my preference) you can search for the App you want to delete with their search function.

[image]

The tool also deletes all of the other files that the application creates but are not located in the application folder (like Launch Daemons)

[image: AppCleaner]

This free app has been indispensable to me for keeping my system tidy when I remove unwanted applications.

Comment: Great! I found many unnecessary components which I deleted.

Comment: Great application which does the work many applications should do to keep the place clean.