# Remove the "Legacy Software" and "Installations" lists of System Information

Tags: logs, macos, system-information

There are a couple of programs listed in *Legacy Software* in the *System Information*:

[image]

Is it possible to remove those entries? They are all old apps I've uninstalled, so there is no need to keep those information.

I already deleted all leftover of these apps located in `Users/[home folder]/Library/Application Support` & `Library/Application Support` and checked my drive with [Funter](https://nektony.com/products/funter) (no vestige was found).

There is also plenty of useless information in the *Installations* list : the same app appears several times(sometimes 30 times) and old apps appear here as well. Is it possible/safe to remove those entries too ?

I'm running Mojave 10.14.6 on a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017)

Comment: Funter just shows you hidden files and toggles the ability to view them easily.  If you want something that will remove all traces of an installed App, see [App Cleaner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231811/119271).  That said, it's not clear what issue you're having, if any.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to erase information in Legacy Software and Installations, as they are both really long list.

Comment: Did you try App Cleaner?

Comment: Just did, nothing to unistall. For example if I type Compressor (as it is listed in the Legacy Software) App Cleaner doesn't find anything. I'm already using CleanMyMac to uninstall things, and double check with Funter afterward to be sure to delete everything...

Comment: Try Command R to Refresh the list, or maybe a restart. System Information does seem to cache the results. Personally I don't trust or rely on cleaning apps.

Comment: Thing is, this is basically a log.  It's not doing anything but providing you info.

Comment: @benwiggy did refresh, everything still there. First entrie is from when I bought my mac (mid 2017). @ Allan I get that it's just info, but I was currious to know if It could be cleared as most info are useless (old apps no more here, or all the update of one...)