# How do I reverse whatever the App "one-sec" did?

Tags: macos, applications

I downloaded an application called [One Sec](https://www.one-sec.app) and I can't open Messages now.

I am not very familiar with how to use Macs as I'm quite old and my wife is telling me to figure it out! Imagine what 57 years of marriage does!

How do I remove this application and undo what it did to my system?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app? I can provide instructions for uninstalling an app if you are unsure how to.

Comment: Hey Ezekiel! I did Uninstall it and also I went into the system preferences to remove its permissions but to no avail.

Comment: I would recommend using the Support link on their website and writing to them. I don't know how long it will take to find someone familiar with the app here so it may be a good idea to send that email sooner than later.

Comment: I recommend a tool called [AppCleaner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/453457/119271) (it’s free).  It will remove the app and all supporting files.

Comment: Hi Allan! Unfortunately, that did not work. I have sent a message to the builder of the app asking for help. Is there a command or something which I can possibly run to allow me to open it?